# Facebook messenger plugin would not close

Tags: javascript, facebook, messenger

I added the messenger plugin script and DIV right above the HEAD section on my HTML.

The plugin does not work as described in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin#steps

Cannot close the text bubble. 
Plugin do not default on hidden for mobile. 
The attributes do not seem to work either. 
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution:

```
<style>
    .fb_customer_chat_bounce_out_v2 { animation-fill-mode: forwards; display: unset !important; }
    .fb_customer_chat_bounce_in_v2 { display: unset !important; }
    .fb_iframe_widget iframe { display: none; }
</style>
```

This worked for me.

Comment: <style>
.fb_customer_chat_bounce_out_v2 { animation-fill-mode: forwards; display: unset !important; }
.fb_customer_chat_bounce_in_v2 { display: unset !important; }
.fb_iframe_widget iframe { display: none; }
</style>

Comment: Update: Many reported this issue [link](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/522187728275011/?hc_location=ufi) and it is already fixed

Answer (score 0):

Until Facebook will fix this bug, you can temporarily fix this by adding display: none to their .fb_customer_chat_bounce_out_v2 class:

`.fb_customer_chat_bounce_out_v2 {
    display: none;
}`

Answer (score 0):

if you select left direction
so you can add this css

```html
<style>
    @keyframes fb_bounce_in_from_right {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: scale(0, 0);
            transform-origin: bottom left
        }
        50% {
            transform: scale(1.03, 1.03);
            transform-origin: bottom left
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: scale(1, 1);
            transform-origin: bottom left
        }
    }
    @keyframes fb_bounce_out_from_right {
        0% {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: scale(1, 1);
            transform-origin: bottom left
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: scale(0, 0);
            transform-origin: bottom left
        }
    }
</style>
```